# Follow path Constraint, relative locations for offset objects

Tags: animation

i made something like this using follow path constraint on 4 objects and 1 curve.[image]

for my project, i need them to become like this. staying at the center but behaving as if they are still on my curve. something like this gif below:
[image]

this may be a noob question but my project depends on your answer :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, (I don't know whether it's the snappiest, or most controllable)

1. Copy the entire rig, track and trucks
2. On the copy, delete all trucks except the copy of the one you want to remain stationary in world space.. 'Target Truck'... ( red in the illustration )
3. Put a Copy Location constraint on the original **track**, targeted on 'Target Truck', World space, X,Y and Z, **all inverted** in the constraint.

[image]

Comment: WOW, u r just amazing. it worked. tho i have to understand this method. seems pretty handy.
thanks again.

Comment: @shiyonsufa     Curious.. how did you make your 2nd gif? I saw it, and thought you must have answered your own question!

Comment: i just used a tracked camera to tell u what i really want :3